# Bending with Lattice modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to bend a simple snake-like model (see the figures) using a curve in order to tune the shape for my needs. I first tried to use the curve modifier, but since I'm already given a mesh with deformed axis it didn't work as expected. I next thought of using the lattice modifier, deformed itself by the curve I set, i.e. I first bend the lattice to match the form of my mesh (using a Bezier curve) and then apply it as a modifier to my mesh.

[image]

Unfortunately, it didn't work either: the lattice twists and squeezes the shape the way I don't want (see the figure).

What am I doing wrong? How to make the mesh deformation follow the curve I specify?

[image]

Comment: Probably you haven't applied transforms on some of your objects. With [curve specified lattice will follow its deformation](http://i.imgur.com/VgzeaXv.gif), and the cube will follow the lattice.

Comment: Thanks @Mr Zak for suggestion, but in my case, the lattice follows the curve, though the mesh doesn't. Which transforms did you mean? The gif looks encouraging!

Comment: The problem is already visible when I'm trying to "align" my mesh: I need to keep it's volume, but however I move it, [it gets squeezed in the best case](http://i.imgur.com/1fzkG95.gif)

Comment: I meant [applying scaling and rotation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) made in Object mode. It can influnce on the modifiers' result, rather drastically sometimes. Still, in your case the mesh does follow the lattice as I saw, it simply gets transformed not in desired way. "Aligning" mesh may be tricky, but you can start with grabbing yours by Z axis (or start tweaking objects' origins etc).

Comment: In the [reference](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) they mention that the lattice should fit around the object, but nothing is mentioned about the origin. Should the origin of the mesh and the lattice match? I tried moving the mesh around, but I still can't get an expected deformation.

Comment: This is [getting ridiculous](http://i.imgur.com/p6jfEB7.png). I applied all possible transforms to my mesh, and that's what I got...

Comment: I'm afraid you should have applied transforms *before* setting modifiers (*or* dropping them, applying, and them adding modifs again). Provided that new data being applied, size and/or location of mesh changes. And Lattice modifier does take it into account, beginning to edit your mesh in another way. I could write an answer here (so not to make these comments to be a stack), but I'm not sure what's the problem. Could you upload file to [blend-exchange](http://http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ? I will try to make your mesh work, either by repairing exhisting or adding new lattice

Comment: Very kind of you. [There you go](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/483/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of mesh already bent, whose volume should be preserved, it can be too complicated to use [Lattice modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/lattice.html?highlight=lattice). Lattice can be edited with using [Curve Modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/curve.html?highlight=curve%20modifier), but the last one may not be applied to it. And the results in this case will be rather unpredictable and bad looking ([for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJUGN.jpg)).

You could edit Lattice by yourself in *Edit mode*, but why ? A good reason not to do that is that you won't be able to use provided curve as a desired shape.

A workaround is to create rig for the mesh.
You add armature, extrude it (I began from right to left). Then you parent mesh to armature (with Automatic weights will suit your needs) and grab / rotate bones as you'd like:

[image]

I used curve as a reference according to which I edited the bones:

[image]

**[Download file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=487)**.